# Chrome extension Can't play meeting audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a google chrome extension using Manifest V2

The goal of the extension is to enable the user to start online meetings within the browser

I developed pages using react, and then inject these pages into an iFrame inside the currently open website

I can capture the audio/video from the user, and I can send it successfully
I receive audio & video streams from the other users that join the meeting, and I can play their video.

The problem is with audio, I receive the stream, but it doesn't play

I tried playing it

- Inside the video player that has the video working
- in an `<audio>` tag in the same location as the video
- in an `<audio>` tag in the first iframe which the user clicked on
- by playing a "silence.mp3" file after the user clicks on the start meeting button, and then adding `<audio>` tags, or even using js (new Audio())
- in the background script

in all of these cases, I couldn't play the audio that is streamed

I'm not even getting an error message in the console

one thing I did notice, is that I can play my own audio (echo my microphone input), and if I add it to an `<audio>` tag with controls visible, it starts counting up. But when I put the attendees audio track on `<audio>` tags, the controls stays at 0:00

Here's the code for the VideoPlayer.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import msg from '../../lib/msg';
import { Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const VideoPlayer = (props) => {
  const { sessionId } = props;
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState([]);
  const [currentParticipant, setCurrentParticipant] = useState(null);
  const [videoTrack, setVideoTrack] = useState(null);
  const [audioTrack, setAudioTrack] = useState(null);
  const [isLocal, setIsLocal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentParticipant) {
      if (currentParticipant.videoTrack) {
        setVideoTrack(currentParticipant.videoTrack);
      } else {
        setVideoTrack(null);
      }
      //set the audio track regardless if it's allowed or not, that's a decision for another function
      if (currentParticipant.audioTrack) {
        setAudioTrack(currentParticipant.audioTrack);
      } else {
        setAudioTrack(null);
      }
    }
  }, [currentParticipant]);

  const videoEl = useRef(null);
  const audioEl = useRef(null);

  /**
   * Set the video element's source
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!videoEl.current || !videoTrack) return;

    videoEl.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([videoTrack]);
  }, [videoEl, videoTrack]);

  /**
   * Set the audio element's source
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!audioEl.current || !audioTrack || isLocal) return;
    audioEl.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([audioTrack]);
  }, [audioEl, isLocal, audioTrack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const reloadParticipants = () => {
      chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (win) {
        var p = win.getParticipants();
        setParticipants(p);
      });
    };
    const updateTracks = async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
      
      chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (win) {
        var participantList = win.getParticipants();
        var index = participantList.findIndex(
          (item) => item.session_id === sessionId
        );
        var participant = participantList[index];
        setCurrentParticipant(participant);
        setIsLocal(participant.local);
      });
    };

    const msgListeners = [
      { action: msg.broadcast.participantListUpdated, fn: reloadParticipants },
      { action: msg.broadcast.tracksUpdated, fn: updateTracks },
    ];
    const initMessageListeners = async () => {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        msgListeners.forEach(async (item) => {
          if (message.action === item.action) {
            await item.fn(message, sender, sendResponse);
          }
        });
      });
    };

    initMessageListeners();
    reloadParticipants();
  }, [sessionId]);

  return (
    <div className="tile-container">
      <audio autoPlay playsInline ref={audioEl} />
      <video
        autoPlay
        muted
        playsInline
        ref={videoEl}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          position: 'absolute',
          objectFit: 'cover',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Then I'm using webpack to package it into a page

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import VideoPlayer from './VideoPlayer';
import './index.css';

render(<VideoPlayer />, window.document.querySelector('#app-container'));
```

I inject this from the content script using this code

```
// at top I have the variable
const videoPlayerUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('/videoPlayer.html');

// I monitor for an event "participant joined" then call the following function
const createParticipantOverlay = (item) => {
    var participantContainer = $(`
    <div id="participant-${item.session_id}" class="bm_videoContainer">
      <iframe
        id="bm_ownerVideoFrame"
        class="bm_videoFrame"
        allow="autoplay *"
        src="${videoPlayerUrl}?session_id=${item.session_id}"
      ></iframe>
      <div id="bm_dragHandler" class="bm_dragHandler"></div>
    </div>`);
    var container = $('#meeting-container');
    container.append(participantContainer);

    var dragHandler = $(`#participant-${item.session_id}`).find(
      '#bm_dragHandler'
    );
    dragHandler.on('mousedown', mouseDown);
    dragHandler.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
    dragHandler.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
  };
```

note: I'm using daily.co for managing the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built something similar last year with Daily and manifest v2 (I work at Daily by the way, so hopefully I can help sort this out!) Here is the participant `Tile` React component I used to get this working for reference: https://github.com/daily-demos/daily-notion-chrome-extension/blob/main/src/pages/Content/components/Tile.jsx

Looking at your code, nothing super obvious is standing out to me.. Is there a public repo I could look at? You may need to listen for more than just the `participant-joined` Daily event. Do you also have an event listener for `participant-updated`?

Comment: One more thing: you may already know this but the Chrome store is no longer supporting manifest v2 (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/). Doesn't matter if this is just a personal project but heads up in case it's not.

Comment: I believe I based my code off of yours then, because I used the daily notion extension as base for react. amazing work btw. -- I'm suspecting it has to do with running the call in the frames, and the isolated environment of the extension, but can't find a way to prove or disprove it. -- The daily-notion extension runs in the context of the ContentScript, I can't do that because it means I'll have to disconnect and reconnnect on page change. -- Thanks for the link about MV2, seems like I need to re-evaluate the project's feasibility for multiple reasons

Comment: Ah, okay. Glad the code was helpful.. not glad Chrome store is sunsetting v2!! We have some upcoming launches at Daily that should make manifest v3 compatible with our libraries but for now manifest 3 is incompatible. :( They've really gotten strict with the CSP.